# ImportError when using read_excel into a data frame

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am encountering an ImportError when trying to use the read_excel function of Pandas.

I have a script which works perfectly reading CSV files and the read_csv function, using argparse to allow command line arguments. I thought I'd try and modify this script so that it could read Excel files.

This is the code that works perfectly for the CSV file.

```
df = pd.read_csv(args.src, header=0, skiprows=Datarow, na_values=bad_data,
             usecols=[timecol, SPcol, PVcol, MVcol], names=['Timestamp', 'SP', 'PV', 'MV'])
```

My code allows for the user to select the starting row and the columns that they want to read data from, and parses them into a new data frame.  All works well.

Using the read_excel function, I originally came up with this:

```
df = pd.read_excel(args.src, skiprows=Datarow, na_values=bad_data,
             parse_cols=[timecol, SPcol, PVcol, MVcol], header=Headerrow)
```

I removed the header argument as it wasn't required. I changed the usecols to parse_cols as per the Pandas documentation.  In the read_csv function I used custom names for the column headers, but it looked like read_excel couldn't do this. So I replaced this functionality with the header argument and allowed the user to set the row number in the Excel source file that contained the column names.

When I ran this script, I got this Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cleanse.py", line 74, in <module>
    parse_cols=[timecol, SPcol, PVcol, MVcol], header=Headerrow)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 163, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 187, in __init__
    import xlrd  # throw an ImportError if we need to
ImportError: No module named xlrd
```

I saw on another post that someone encountering this error was replied with "pip install xlrd", so I did that. Same problem.  I then started dropping off the optional arguments one at a time.  Same problem.  I went right back to just the source file argument and still get the same error.

Any hints or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Try running the same python you are running for this (e.g., if you are running your script with `python myscript.py` then do just `python`) and try `import xlrd`.  Does it work?

Comment: No. Same ImportError.  I've just deactivated my virtualenv, installed xlrd in my venv folder, reactivated and tried again.  The ImportError has gone away!  I have another error but I'll try and sort this out next.  Thank you!